# How does Twitter perform a redirect when Javascript is disabled?

Tags: javascript, redirection

I have the understanding that disabling JavaScript on a website prevents any scripts from running — I will get the site contents, raw and unevaluated.

But when I disable JavaScript (on Chrome) on `twitter.com`, **I am redirected to `mobile.twitter.com`**. I can't pause the browser on load using `debugger` or the like, since JavaScript is disabled. And the redirect happens too fast anyways. (This is doubly annoying since I can't go back to `twitter.com` to un-disable JavaScript!)

So, how is Twitter

1. detecting that I have JavaScript disabled and
2. performing a redirect without JavaScript?

And, how do I stop this from happening?

edit: Twitter now has a comfirmation screen before redirecting, but in the past it automatically did a redirect without any prompt. I'd like to know how they did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all redirects are based on JavaScript or require active involvement of your browser.

One way this can be done is via a "[meta-refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh)" page that is set to immediately refresh on a different page, in your case the mobile site.

So how does Twitter know to give you this page? Because your web browser told it to. On every request for a document your browser will send a [useragent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string telling the website what browser, OS and version details.

The useragent string is intended to make it possible for a web server to detect and send a version of a webpage that is specifically supported by the requesting device. In the past this was done to make sites that were tailored to the somewhat sporadic support for functionality across browsers.

What it means though is that they can easily detect and redirect mobile users to a more friendly interface.

To get around this most browsers can be set to "request desktop site" which changes their useragent string to pretend your device is a desktop browser.